# When can automatic return type apply?

Tags: c++, c++14

**What are the rules**, that allow [writing](http://ideone.com/4iV7YY) automatic return types in c++1y ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto f(T1 const& a, T2 const &b)
{
    if (a > b) return a-b;
    else return a+b;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << f(1, 2.) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a limit imposed by the cyclomatic complexity of a function's body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Introduction**

There are a few simple rules that states when the *return-type* of a function can be deduced from the *function body*, and with that when `auto` is applicable as *return-type*.

These rules are all stated in the Standard ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) <sup>[1]</sup>,  and each rule is listed in it's own section in the remaining parts of this post.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup>  in section *7.1.6.4, **auto specifier**  `[dcl.type.elab]`*.</sup>

---

**Is there anything that can't be deduced using `auto` as the return-type?**

> **`[dcl.type.elab]p1`** If the deduction is for a `return` statement and the initializer is a braced-init-list (8.5.4), the program is ill-formed.

```
auto func () { return {1,2,3}; } // ill-formed
```

---

**Which type will be deduced if a function has more than one *return-statement*?**

> **`[dcl.type.elab]p9`** If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple return statements, the return type is deduced for each return statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.

```
auto gunc_1 (bool val) { // (1), ill-formed
  if (val) return 123;
  else     return 3.14f;
}
```

```
auto gunc_2 (bool val) { // (2), legal
  if (val) return static_cast<float> (123);
  else     return 3.14f;
}
```

<sup>**Note**: *(1)* is ill-formed since all *return-statements* are not of the same type, whereas *(2)* is legal since the two *return-statements* yields the same type.</sup>

---

**What happens if the function doesn't have a *return-statement*?**

> **`[dcl.type.elab]p10`** If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type has no return statements, the return type is deduced as though from a return statement with no operand at the closing brace of the function body.

```
auto hunc () { } // legal, return-type is `void`
```

---

**Can I use the function, before the return-type has been deduced?**

> **`[dcl.type.elab]p11`** If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed. Once a return statement has been seen in a function, however, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.

```
auto junc (); // declaration

void foo () { &junc; } // (1), ill-formed

auto junc () { // definition
   return 123;
}

void bar () { &junc; } // (2), legal
```

```
auto recursive (int x) {
  if (--x) return x + recursive (x); // (3), ill-formed
  else     return 0;
}
```

<sup>**Note**: We cannot take the address of `junc` inside `foo` since doing that requires knowledge about what the complete type of `junc` is, something which isn't know until we have provided a definition where the return-type has been deduced. *(2)* is therefor legal, whereas *(1)* isn't.</sup>

<sup>**Note**: *(3)* is also ill-formed since we must know the return-type of `recursive` at this point, but it isn't known. Having the return-statements in the opposite order would, however, be valid. That way the compiler would know `recursive` to return `int` when it hits `return x + recursive (x)`.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a limit imposed by the cyclomatic complexity of a function's
>   body?

### What the standard specifies (N3797, §7.1.6.4):

> Let `T` be the declared type of the variable or return type of the
>   function.  If the placeholder is the `auto` *type-specifier*, the deduced
>   type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If
>   the deduction is for a `return` statement and the initializer is a
>   *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), the program is ill-formed.  Otherwise,
>   obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new
>   invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initializer is a
>   *braced-init-list*, with `std::initializer_list<U>`. Deduce a value for
>   `U` using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call
>   (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a function template parameter type and the
>   initializer is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the
>   declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, the type deduced for the
>   variable or return type is obtained by substituting the deduced `U` into
>   `P`.

So, tl;dr: the return type is deduced from the expression in the `return` statement via template argument deduction. There is an imaginary template which is called with the expressions in the `return` statements as function arguments, and the deduced template argument `U` will be the replacement for the auto in the placeholder return type.
Now, what happens if we have **more than one return statement?** Simple: We deduce for every `return` statement, and check whether they are compatible:

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder
>   type has multiple `return` statements, the return type is deduced for
>   each `return` statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each
>   deduction, nthe program is ill-formed.

So, for this code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto f(T1 const& a, T2 const &b)
{
    if (a > b) return a-b;
    else return a+b;
}
```

The following deduction is done:

```
template<typename U>
void g(U);

g( a-b ); 
g( a+b );
// here, a and b have the exact same types as in a specialization of the template above.
```

If, and only if, in both calls the same template argument is deduced, the code is well-formed. Otherwise, the deduction fails. If the return type you set with the auto specifier is not a simple `auto` but for example `auto const&`, the parameter of the imaginary template `g` has the corresponding form:

```
template<typename U>
void g(U const&);
```

And the calls will be the same. Again, if the deduced `U`s differ, the code is ill-formed.

In case you have **no return statement**, the deduced return type will be `void`, according to

> If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type
>   has no `return` statements, the return type is deduced as though from
>   a `return` statement with no operand at the closing brace of the
>   function body.

#### recursion

It gets more tricky if you want **recursive functions**:

```
auto f( int a, int b )
{
    return a? b + a : f(a-1, b); // This is ill-formed!
}
```

The problem is explained by the following quote:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.
>   Once a `return` statement has been seen in a function, however, the
>   return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the
>   function, including in other `return` statements.

So instead we write:

```
auto f( int a, int b )
{
    if( a )
        return b + a;

    return f(a-1, b);
}
```

### Conclusion:

You can use arbitrarily complex functions, as long as the `return` statements all yield the same type during deduction and recursive functions have the recursive calls after some non-recursive `return`-statements. Cast if necessary to get the same types.

Comment: Great answer, sounds like an absolutely horrible thing to implement if you're a compiler writer.

Comment: Meh, by far not as bad as other stuff inside a compiler. ;)
(take for instance the `export`-keyword in C++03)